# getchar is able to read ctrl+z but not scanf?

Tags: c, windows, scanf, getchar

What I want to do is find out if scanf can read ctrl+z as EOF? I know that getchar and scanf return EOF when the end of the file is reached. This I have no problem with. What I want to do is have them read EOF or ctrl+z to the parameter(and not look at the return-value), is this possible?

First I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int d;

    d = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", d);

}

/*Output:
^Z
-1
*/
```

As you can see there is no problem with getchar. But with scanf I get this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int d;

    scanf_s("%d", &d);
    printf("%d\n", d);

}
/*
Output:
^Z

*/
```

Nothing happens when I press ctrl+z and hit enter. Could you please explain why it works with getchar but not with scanf?, and what must I do to make it work?

Comment: `scanf` returns a value, check that.

Comment: And initialize `d` to a known value or you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: `scanf` is, well, a scanner. It is normal for it to read (scan) nothing, and this is why it returns an `ìnt` (that your discarded). As for `d`,  it is a static variable, and it will keep its previous value, one that you did not set. The same reason makes `fgets` return `char*`: it is a way to tell the caller it read got nothing from the stream. And the buffer goes unchanged.

Comment: When it encounters EOF (in the form of control-Z), `scanf_s()` stops scanning and, because it hasn't read any data at all, returns EOF (as the function return value) and leaves `d` untouched.  If it had read a blank or something, it would return 0 instead of EOF.  Even if you used a format string like `"%c"` and passed a pointer to a `char` variable, you'd still get nothing assigned to the variable and `scanf_s()` would return EOF.

Comment: Windows console handling of CtrlZ is pretty picky (flaky). With that code I have to press `CtrlZ` `Enter` three times to get it to quit. But then, the behaviour is undefined because you try to output `d` which has never been set with a value. Unlike `getchar()` the EOF value does not arrive in `d`. It's not a true input value anyway: it is a flag.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I set d to 0 to avoid getting UB. Then I also had to press ctrl+z 3 times, and then d is untouched, but you have explained that.