# Does getchar read ctrl+z or return EOF?

Tags: c, windows, eof, getchar

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int d=0;

d = getchar();
printf("%d\n", d);

}
```

Output:

```
^Z
-1
```

From what I understand there are two things that could be happening here:

1. Getchar reads ctrl+z and it returns it.
2. Getchar reads nothing and returns EOF.

Are there any more possibilities?, which of the two is correct?

Comment: The `^Z` you see isn't an input value: it is the echo from the keyboard handler, as with other keys you press. Option 3, `getchar()` reads the `Ctrl-Z` value `26` and converts it to the `EOF` flag.

Comment: In this case the value is assigned to `d` anyway. In your previous [scanf example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78211381/getchar-is-able-to-read-ctrlz-but-not-scanf) it was not.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you very much! I just have one follow-up question: When I look at the ASCII table it says that 25 is "end of medium", and 26 is "substitute". Could it be that it is 25 and not 26?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. What `getchar()` does.
2. What the console/OS/run-time environment does.

What `getchar()` does is clear:

*Returns EOF (-1) on *any* failure. If the failure is caused by end-of-file additionally sets the eof indicator (see `feof()` on stdin).*

What the OS console does in this case (Windows):

1. Receive input Ctrl-Z (non- printing ASCII control character 26)
2. Echoes non-printing Ctrl-Z as `^Z`
3. Traps Ctrl-Z as EOF and inserts EOF into stdin (not Chr.26).

Noting that Ctrl-Z (SUB) is peculiar to Windows, MS-DOS and before that CP/M. In CP/M SUB was used to pad files to a multiple of 128 bytes (a requirement of its primitive filesystem), so for files that are not a multiple 128 bytes it essentially marked the end-of-file.  On Unix and Linux Ctrl-D (EOT - end-of-transmission) is used which arguably makes more sense, but neither is truly an end-of-file, the terminology comes from treating `stdin` as a "file" stream, which simplifies device driver interfaces and redirection.

So in summary, the *system* (Windows) treats Ctrl-Z in the console as an instruction to insert an EOF into the console input stream, and `getchar()` returns EOF, and sets the input stream's EOF flag. The echoing of `^Z` (or any character) is a platform specific [*side-effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIn_computer_science%2C_an_operation%2Cthe_invoker_of_the_operation.?wprov=sfla1).  `getchar()` does not in fact echo anything.

It is not truly the end of the stream, and input can resume after calling one of `rewind()`, `fsetpos()`, `fseek()`, or `clearerr()`.

Note also that this is strictly behaviour of the *console* input stream.  If `stdin` were redirected from a file , EOF would be indicated at the true end-of-file, and that file could contain Ctrl-Z (SUB) characters, and these would be returned by `getchar()` as value 26.

Comment: As side note, when a file is opened in text mode in Windows, a character 26 is treated as it was in the old days and the file read ends at that point.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it is Windows and not getchar that converts 26 to -1? You say "So in summary, the system (Windows) treats Ctrl-Z in the console as an instruction to insert an EOF into the console input stream", does this mean it inserts -1 into the console input stream?

Comment: @user394334 I am really saying it is "as if" the EOF were inserted into the steam.  The exact underlying implementation may not do exactly that.  It is a model of behaviour that suits the purpose of writing code using stdio.  If you want more control at a lower level, use the [Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)

Comment: Last question: So after that does getchar look in the stream, and detects the EOF that Windows put into the stream, and return EOF, which now is -1(that is getchar sets it as -1?)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I have learned something.  But then again a non printing character in the middle of a text file would be unusual. I may have to test my assertion that it does not cause EOF when redirecting to stdin.

Comment: I did check that before posting my comment.

Comment: @user394334 who knows? Does it matter? And isn't that the same as your previous question? The point about a "model" of behaviour is it does not have to be internally accurate.  It merely needs to match any externally observable behaviour.

Comment: @user394334 it doesn't matter how it happens. In the case of redirecting a file input there is no Crtl-Z or Ctrl-D (subject to my first comment).

Comment: Clifford my guess is that it is to retain compatibility with ancient text files from before NT. Of course, the 0x1A is probably not in the middle of a file but at the end, and it is desirable not to read that as a character (it's not text anyway).